# PHP combine two arrays using key values

Tags: php, arrays, merge

This question may sound silly, but I didn't find a good approach.

I have to multidimensional arrays like this:-

```
array 
(
  [0] => Array
      (
        [field1] => A
        [field2] => 100
        [field3] => 20
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
        [field1] => B
        [field2] => 100
        [field3] => 30
      )
  [2] => Array
      (
        [field1] => C
        [field2] => 100
        [field3] => 30
      )
)



 array 
(
  [0] => Array
      (
        [field1b] => A
        [field2b] => 500
        [field3b] => 0
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
        [field1b] => B
        [field2b] => 300
        [field3b] => 10
      )
)
```

I want to merge both arrays using field1 as Key, and having in mind that arrays aren't same size.

The result array should be:

```
array 
(
  [0] => Array
      (
        [field1] => A
        [field2] => 100
        [field3] => 20
        [field2b] => 500
        [field3b] => 0

      )

  [1] => Array
      (
        [field1] => B
        [field2] => 100
        [field3] => 30
        [field2b] => 300
        [field3b] => 10
      )
  [2] => Array
      (
        [field1] => C
        [field2] => 100
        [field3] => 30
      )
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have you tried: `array_merge_recursive` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: user3472675   you have answers below, check them and mark one answer as accepted which seems to you more correct.Thanks

Comment: Done! Hung Hoai gimme the key!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$array1 =  array 
(
  "0" => Array
      (
        "field1" => "A",
        "field2" => "100",
        "field3" => "20"
      ),

  "1" => Array
      (
        "field1" => "B",
        "field2" => "100",
        "field3" => "30"
      ),
  "2" => Array
      (
        "field1" => "C",
        "field2" => "100",
        "field3" => "30"
      )
);

$array2 =  array 
(
  "0" => Array
      (
        "field1b" => "A",
        "field2b" => "500",
        "field3b" => "0"
      ),

  "1" => Array
      (
        "field1b" => "B",
        "field2b" => "300",
        "field3b" => "10"
      )
);

$new_array1 = [];
foreach ($array1 as $object1) {
  $new_array1[$object1['field1']] =  $object1;
}

$new_array2 = [];
foreach ($array2 as $key => $object2) {
  $new_array2[$object2['field1b']] =  $object2;
}
$new_array = [];
foreach($new_array1 as $key => $val)
{
    $new_array[$key]['field1'] = $val['field1'];
    $new_array[$key]['field2'] = $val['field2'];
    $new_array[$key]['field3'] = $val['field3'];
    if (array_key_exists($key,$new_array2))//Check if the key is exists in an array
    {
      $new_array[$key]['field2b'] = $new_array2[$key]['field2b'];
      $new_array[$key]['field3b'] = $new_array2[$key]['field3b'];
    }       
}

print_r($new_array);
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/661822)

You can try it.

Comment: Simply brilliant! :) Thanks a lot! This is exactly the approach I need!

Comment: @user3472675 this much foreach is no-where a brilliant idea. Simple thing, no need to make it so complex. May be it answers correctly, but definitely not the nicest one.

Comment: @user3472675  also if this one is your acceptable answer then why you said this initially:- `This question may sound silly, but I didn't find a good approach.`

Comment: @Anant much foreach beacause we need set value "field1" and value "field1b" is key for array. Because what is he need is merge value "field1" and value "field1b" of arrays. He don't need to merge key with key. Have you a better idea for use only one foreach?

Comment: @Anant I checked and run in https://eval.in/662990
I added more data into $arr2 and your code did not support

Comment: @Anant Perfect! Remember refactoring your code for easy to read.
https://deliciousbrains.com/refactoring-php-code-better-readability/

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
$array1 =  array 
(
  "0" => Array
      (
        "field1" => "A",
        "field2" => "100",
        "field3" => "20"
      ),

  "1" => Array
      (
        "field1" => "B",
        "field2" => "100",
        "field3" => "30"
      ),
  "2" => Array
      (
        "field1" => "C",
        "field2" => "100",
        "field3" => "30"
      )
);



$array2 =  array 
(
  "0" => Array
      (
        "field1b" => "A",
        "field2b" => "500",
        "field3b" => "0"
      ),

  "1" => Array
      (
        "field1b" => "B",
        "field2b" => "300",
        "field3b" => "10"
      )
);

foreach($array1 as $key=>$val)
{
    $new_array[$key]['field1'] = $val['field1'];
    $new_array[$key]['field2'] = $val['field2'];
    $new_array[$key]['field3'] = $val['field3'];
    if (array_key_exists($key,$array2))//Check if the key is exists in an array
    {
      $new_array[$key]['field2b'] = $array2[$key]['field2b'];
      $new_array[$key]['field3b'] = $array2[$key]['field3b'];
    }       
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/661797)**

Answer (score 3):

Very simple:- apply `foreach` and do it like below:-

```
<?php
$final_array = array();

foreach ($arr1 as $key=>$val){
   if(isset($arr2[$key])){
      $final_array[$key] = array_merge($val,$arr2[$key]);
      unset($final_array[$key]['field1b']);
   }else{
      $final_array[$key] = $val;
   }

}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/661803

***If your both array have different number of elements then :-***

```
  <?php
  $count1 = count ($arr1);
  $count2 = count ($arr2);
  $final_array = array();  
  if ($count1 >$count2){
    foreach ($arr1 as $key=>$val){
       if(isset($arr2[$key])){
          $final_array[$key] = array_merge($val,$arr2[$key]);
          unset($final_array[$key]['field1b']);
       }else{
          $final_array[$key] = $val;
       }
    }
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
  }else if ($count2 >$count1){
    foreach ($arr2 as $key=>$val){
       if(isset($arr1[$key])){
          $final_array[$key] = array_merge($val,$arr1[$key]);
          unset($final_array[$key]['field1b']);
       }else{
          $final_array[$key] = $val;
       }
    }
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
  }else{
    foreach ($arr1 as $key=>$val){
       if(isset($arr2[$key])){
          $final_array[$key] = array_merge($val,$arr2[$key]);
          unset($final_array[$key]['field1b']);
       }else{
          $final_array[$key] = $val;
       }

    }
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this instead defining hard-coded keys condition? all you need is to provide the key which should not be included in combined array..

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/jwWlAx)

```
<?php
$A        = array(
    array(
        'field1' => 'A',
        'field2' => '100',
        'field3' => '20',
    ),
    array(
        'field1' => 'B',
        'field2' => 100,
        'field3' => 30,
    ),
    array(
        'field1' => 'C',
        'field2' => 100,
        'field3' => 30,
    )
);
$B        = array(
    array(
        'field1b' => 'A',
        'field2b' => 500,
        'field3b' => 0
    ),
    array(
        'field1b' => 'B',
        'field2b' => 300,
        'field3b' => 10
    )
);
$combined = array();
foreach($A as $key => $arr) {
    $tempKey    = reset($arr);
    $second_arr = $B[ $key ];
    $tempKey2   = reset($B[ $key ]);
    if( $tempKey == $tempKey2 ) {
        $combined[] = $arr + $second_arr;
        unset( $combined[ $key ]['field1b'] );
    }
    else {
        $combined[] = $arr;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($combined);
echo '</pre>';
```